# why it will cost 60 seconds run every sudo command

Tags: centos, sudo

After the last system update on my centos, it will almost cost 60s for every command when I use sudo or even login as root.
I use `strace sudo ls` to see what happened, here is some key log

```
mprotect(0x7fe8c9245000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fe8cec96000, 30963)           = 0  
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 6  
fcntl(6, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(6, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC|0x2)       = 0  
connect(6, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/nslcd/socket"}, 19) = 0
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 10000) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(6, "\0\0\0\2\0\4\0\6\0\0\0\4root", 16, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 16 
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 60000) = 0 (Timeout)
close(6)
```

fd detail

```
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May  5 11:15 0 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May  5 11:15 1 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May  5 11:15 2 -> /dev/pts/2
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 May  5 11:15 3 -> /var/lib/sss/mc/passwd
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 May  5 11:15 4 -> /etc/sudoers
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 May  5 11:16 5 -> /var/lib/sss/mc/initgroups
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May  5 11:15 6 -> 'socket:[243209288]'
```

Can anyone help me figure out what happened and solve this.

Comment: `nscld` is `local LDAP name service daemon`, therefore your system is trying to contact it and will timeout after some configured delay. Either disable it, or fix the ldap server.